# PHP- Asking the User Input- Calculating

Tags: php

I have being trying to make this simple program work, but for some reason, I am not getting any results. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    Price of the Meal
    <input value="100" type="text" name="meal"><br>
    Tip
    <input value="20" type="text" name="tip">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">


    <?php
    $meal = $_POST['meal'];
    $tip = $_POST['tip'];

    $total_amount = check($meal, 10, $tip);

    function check($meal, $tax, $tip) {

        $tax_amount = $meal * .10;

        $tip_amount = $meal * ($tip / 100);

        $total_amount = $meal + $tax_amount + $tip_amount;
        echo "Price of the meal " . $meal . "\n";


        echo "tax_amount " . $tax_amount . "\n";
        echo "tip_amount " . $tip_amount . "\n";

        return $total_amount;
    }

    echo "Total " . $total_amount;
    ?>
```

Comment: What results are you expecting? What results are you getting (this includes browser display *and* log files)? Do other simple php "Hello world" style pages work?

Comment: I just want to calculate the tax amount, and the tip amount after the user inputs the meal. Thanks

Comment: ... and what results are you getting rather than the ones you are expecting?  I don't have php installed on my local web machine, I can't run your code so I don't know what its doing - what results are it giving for the various inputs you are giving it?  I *might* be able to walk through to see *if* you tell me what your inputs are, outputs are, and expected outputs are.

Comment: Paste in a view source on the result for us to see. If it's not submitting at all, consider closing your <form> element. Not sure whether browsers are fussy about that or not.

Comment: Hi </form> tag is missing in your form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working with little change

```
$tax_amount = $meal * ($tax/100);
```

and add conditions

```
 if (isset($_POST['meal']) && isset($_POST['tip']) && $_POST['meal'] > 0 && $_POST['tip'] > 0) {
  echo "Price of the meal " . $meal . "\n";
  echo "tax_amount " . $tax_amount . "\n";
  echo "tip_amount " . $tip_amount . "\n";
}


if (isset($_POST['meal']) && isset($_POST['tip']) && $_POST['meal'] > 0 && $_POST['tip'] > 0)
  echo "Total " . $total_amount;
```